# How to Preselect Multiple Listbox Items?

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

For part of a project I'm working on (a random date selector), I created an edit window with a Listbox filled with categories for dates, where a user can toggle categories for the date selected on a first Listbox. I want to preselect all categories that are already in the list of categories in the date object.

I've tried to do this with a simple for loop like so:

```
dateCategoryList = Listbox(editDateWindow, height=5, width=40, font="none 10", selectmode="multiple")
for i in dateCategories:
    dateCategoryListbox.insert(len(dateCategories), i.name)
    for j in dateListbox.curselection():
        if i.name in dates[j].categories:
            dateCategoryList.selection_set(dateCategoryList.size() - 1)
```

...but that only activates the first item in the loop.

I also thought about dividing the Listbox into two to easily sort items, but I'd rather keep it simple if possible. Is there another way to preselect multiple items in a Listbox?

Comment: Could you create a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can better help you?

Answer (score 1):

You can programmatically select (multiple) items by calling the [`Listbox.selection_set()`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/listbox.html) method for each one:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

listbox = tk.Listbox(root, selectmode="multiple")
listbox.insert(1, "New York")
listbox.insert(2, "Los Angeles")
listbox.insert(3, "Chicago")
listbox.insert(4, "Houston")
listbox.insert(5, "Phoenix")
listbox.insert(6, "Philadelphia")

listbox.pack()

for i in (2, 3, 5):
    listbox.selection_set(i-1)

root.mainloop()
```

Here's what it displays on my system:

[image: Screenshot]: